# Android Facebook SDK open graph story not showing in foreground before posting

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I got the sample code to post facebook open graph custom story from developers.facebook.com. 
I want the android app to show the story posting dialogue to the user so the user can add some custom text before publishing the story.
The below code posts the story in the background. i.e. user is not aware that a facebook open graph story is posted to there account. 
Please can anyone help.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
String eventUrl = AppConstants.OPEN_GRAPH_EVENT_URL + SessionStore.getInstance().getEventId();
String partnerUrl = AppConstants.OPEN_GRAPH_PARTNER_URL + SessionStore.getInstance().getOrgIdOfEvent();
params.putString("eventname", eventUrl);
params.putString("partnername", partnerUrl);
params.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");


GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "me/bcastpoll:voted",
        params,
        HttpMethod.POST
    );

    FacebookPostAsyncTask async = new FacebookPostAsyncTask(SessionStore.getInstance().getCurrentContext(), request);
    async.execute("");
```

Async task code

```
public class FacebookPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    Context ctx;
    GraphRequest request; 

    GraphResponse response; 
    public FacebookPostAsyncTask(Context ctx, GraphRequest request ) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.request  = request ;   
    }

    public FacebookPostAsyncTask() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        response = request.executeAndWait();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (response.getError() != null)
            Toast.makeText(SessionStore.getInstance().getCurrentContext(), response.getError().getErrorUserMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ((QuestionsActivity)ctx).onFacebookPost();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the explicitly shared parameter.

fb:explicitly_shared=true

Further info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#explicit